# Ruby on Rails: Remove blank entries in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, drop-down-menu

I have an app where the user can create a new project and search for previous projects. On the "create new project" page, the user has the option to enter new info for each field, or select from dropdown menus, if the data is already in the database. As for the search function on the search page. The user can search on many different fields, multiple ways.

**UPDATE:**

Following a suggestion below, I have gone ahead a built a table that holds the many technologies per project.

**Search action**

```
def search

@search = params[:client], params[:industry], params[:role], params[:tech_id], params[:business_div], params[:project_owner], params[:status], params[:start_date_dd], params[:start_date_A], params[:start_date_B],  params[:keywords]

@project_search = Project.search(*@search).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).paginated_for_index(per_page, page)

@search_performed = !@search.reject! { |c| c.blank? }.empty? 

   @project = Project.new(params[:project])


@all_technols = Technol.all

@technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

params[:technols][:id].each do |technol|

if !technol.empty?

@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technol)

end
end

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # search.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end

end
```

**New action:**

```
def new
    @project = Project.new

@all_technols = Technol.all

@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build


@project_technol = Projecttechnol.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @project }
    end
```

end

**Create action**

```
def create
    @all_technols = Technol.all
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

@technol = Technol.new(params[:tech])

params[:technols][:id].each do |technol|

if !technol.empty?



@project_technol = @project.projecttechnols.build(:technol_id => technol)

end
end
    @project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
    @project.project_owner = params[:new_project_owner] unless params[:new_project_owner].blank?
    @project.tech = params[:new_tech] unless params[:new_tech].blank?
    @project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
    @project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
    @project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Tech part of the new view:**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "new" %>


<h1>Create New Project</h1>





<div class="tech">
<%#= label_tag :new_tech, "Technologies Used :" %><br/>


<%= text_field_tag :new_tech, nil, :maxlength => 30 %>

Or
<%#= f.select( :tech, Project.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq, { :prompt => "Select a previous Technology"}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }) %>
<!/div>  

<% common_techs = [['Mainframe'],['UNIX'],['Windows Servers'],['Networking'],['CISCO'], ['Win7'], ['Telephony'], ['Web services'], ['Website'], ['Cloud'], ['Virtualisation'], ['Data Centre']] %>
 <% db_techs = Technol.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq %>

<% all_tech = common_techs + db_techs %>


<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>




<%= ab.label "Select previous technologies" %><br/>

<%= collection_select(:technols, :id, @all_technols, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true} ) %>
</div>
<% end %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "new" %>


<h1>Create New Project</h1>





<div class="tech">
<%#= label_tag :new_tech, "Technologies Used :" %><br/>


<%= text_field_tag :new_tech, nil, :maxlength => 30 %>

Or
<%#= f.select( :tech, Project.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq, { :prompt => "Select a previous Technology"}, { :multiple => true, :size => 5 }) %>
<!/div>  

<% common_techs = [['Mainframe'],['UNIX'],['Windows Servers'],['Networking'],['CISCO'], ['Win7'], ['Telephony'], ['Web services'], ['Website'], ['Cloud'], ['Virtualisation'], ['Data Centre']] %>
 <% db_techs = Technol.all.map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq %>

<% all_tech = common_techs + db_techs %>


<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>




<%= ab.label "Select previous technologies" %><br/>

<%= collection_select(:technols, :id, @all_technols, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true} ) %>
</div>
<% end %>





</div> <%#= small div %>





<% end %>



<div class="back_button2">
<%= button_to "Back", projects_path , :class => "button", :method => "get" %>
</div>



</div> <%#= small div %>





<% end %>



<div class="back_button2">
<%= button_to "Back", projects_path , :class => "button", :method => "get" %>
</div>
```

**Search Page:**

```
<html>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "search" %>
<body>
<div id ="title1">Exception Database Search</div>
<div id = "search_op">

<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>


<div class="client">
Client : 
<%= select(@projects, :client, Project.order("client").map{|p| [p.client]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:client]) %></br>
</div>

<div class="industry">
Industry :
<%= select(@projects, :industry, Project.order("industry").map {|p| [p.industry]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:industry]) %></br>
</div>

<div class="role">
Role :
<%= select(@projects, :role, Project.order("role").map {|p| [p.role]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:role]) %></br>
</div>

<div class="tech">

<% common_techs = [['Mainframe'],['UNIX'],['Windows Servers'],['Networking'],['CISCO'], ['Win7'], ['Telephony'], ['Web services'], ['Website'], ['Cloud'], ['Virtualisation'], ['Data Centre']] %>
 <% db_techs = Project.order("tech").map {|p| [p.tech]}.uniq %>

<% all_tech = Project.order("tech").map {|p| [p.tech]} + Project.order("tech").map {|p| [p.tech2]} + Project.order("tech").map {|p| [p.tech3]} + Project.order("tech").map {|p| [p.tech4]} + Project.order("tech").map {|p| [p.tech5]} %>





<%= fields_for(@project_technol) do |ab| %>



<%= collection_select(:technols, :id, @all_technols, :id, :tech, {}, {:multiple => true } ) %>
</div>
<% end %>


<div class="business_div">
Business Division :

<%= select(@projects, :business_div, Project.order("business_div").map {|p| [p.business_div]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:business_div]) %></br>
</div>


<div class="project_owner">  
Project Owner :
<%= select(@projects, :project_owner, Project.order("project_owner").map {|p| [p.project_owner]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:project_owner]) %></br>
</div>


<div class="date1">
Select start dates from :
<%= select_tag "start_date_dd", options_for_select({
    "Select a period" => "",
      "3 days ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 3.days,   # =    259_200 sec.
      "1 week ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.week,   # =    604_800 sec.
      "1 month ago"  => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.month,  # =  2_592_000 sec.
      "6 months ago" => DateTime.now.to_date - 6.months, # = 15_552_000 sec.
      "1 year ago"   => DateTime.now.to_date - 1.year,   # = 31_557_600 sec.
    }, :selected=>params[:start_date_dd] )%>

</div>

<%#= until now <%= l DateTime.now.to_date %><%#=,%>   
<h4> OR</h4> 

<div class="date2">
exact start dates

<%=  text_field_tag :start_date_A, params[:start_date_A], :style => 'width: 80px;' %>


-

<%=  text_field_tag :start_date_B, params[:start_date_B], :style => 'width: 80px;' %></br>
</div>






<div class="status">
Status :

<%= select(@projects, :status, Project.order("status").map {|p| [p.status]}.uniq, :prompt => "-Any-", :selected => params[:status]) %></br>
</div>



<div class="keywords">
Keywords :

<%= text_field_tag :keywords, params[:keywords] %></br>
</div>




<div class="results">
Results per page: <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,50], :selected=>params[:per_page]),  { :onchange => "this.form.submit();"}   %></br>


<div class="buttons">
<div id="search_button">
<%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, :class => "button" %>
</div>

<% end %>

<div class="home_button">
<%= button_to "Home", projects_path, :class => "button", :method => "get"  %>
</div>



<div id="reset_button">
<%= button_to "Reset Search", search_path, :class => "button", :method => "get" %>
</div>


</div>
</div> <%#search_op div%>







<div class ="menu"></div>



<div id ="section3">

<% if @project_search.total_entries > 0 %>
<% if @search_performed %>





<% if @search_performed %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :per_page, params[:per_page] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :page, params[:page] %>


<%= will_paginate (@project_search), :class => 'will' %>

<% end %>



</body>


</html>
```

**Models:**

```
class Projecttechnol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_id, :technol_id

belongs_to :technol
belongs_to :project
end

class Technol < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tech

has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :projects, :through => :projecttechnols
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :edited_first_name, :edited_last_name, :first_name, :last_name, :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :edited_date, :end_date, :entry_date,  :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary, :tech_id

validates_presence_of :business_div, :client, :customer_benifits, :end_date,  :financials, :industry, :keywords, :lessons_learned, :project_name, :project_owner, :role, :start_date, :status, :summary#, :tech


validates_format_of :industry, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "field should only have letters"
validates_format_of :business_div, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "field should only have letters"
validates_format_of :client, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "field should only have letters"
validates_format_of :project_owner, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "field should only have letters"
validates_format_of :role, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "field should only have letters"

has_many :projecttechnols
has_many :technols, :through => :projecttechnols


def self.like(text); "%#{text}%"; end

  def self.search(search_client, search_industry, search_role, search_tech_id, search_business_div, search_project_owner, search_exception_pm, search_status, search_start_date_dd, search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B,  search_keywords)
    # start with a scoped query, to apply more scopes on it afterwards
    _projects = Project.scoped 
    # then, for each of the parameters, apply the scope only if present
    if search_client.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['client LIKE ?', like(search_client)] 
    end
    if search_industry.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['industry LIKE ?', like(search_industry)]
    end
    if search_role.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['role LIKE ?', like(search_role)]
    end


    if search_tech_id.present?
  _projects = _projects.joins(:technols).where("tech.id" => search_tech_id)
end

    if search_business_div.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['business_div LIKE ?', like(search_business_div)]
    end
    if search_project_owner.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['project_owner LIKE ?', like(search_project_owner)]
    end

     if search_status.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['status LIKE ?', like(search_status)]
    end



todays_date = DateTime.now.to_date

if !search_start_date_A.blank? or !search_start_date_B.blank?
    search_start_date_A = Date.parse(search_start_date_A).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    search_start_date_B = Date.parse(search_start_date_B).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    todays_date = nil
    search_start_date_dd = nil

    end

if search_start_date_dd.blank?
    todays_date = nil
end


if search_start_date_A.present? or search_start_date_B.present?

      _projects = _projects.where [' DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', search_start_date_A, search_start_date_B]
    end


                if search_start_date_dd.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['DATE(start_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', search_start_date_dd, todays_date]
    end




    if search_keywords.present?
      _projects = _projects.where ['keywords LIKE ?', like(search_keywords)]
    end
    # now you have applied only the present scopes. return the result, and watch 
    # the query as it executes.
    _projects
  end


def self.paginated_for_index(projects_per_page, current_page)
    paginate(:per_page => projects_per_page, :page => current_page)
  end

end
```

I can't seem to get the new technologys on the "new project page" to save in the Technols table. I also can't get the search to work properly. Searching for anything in the technology field returns nothing.

Comment: I have, I just left the code out my question. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, third question of yours about the same project, it starts to be clear where you want to go.

Have you considered storing technologies in a separate table, and an additional join table for the relationship to the Product table?

This way you can select any number of techs for a project, you can search using only one field (it will get only projects related to the chosen technology) and you won't have such complex code.

Use a select tag to choose the technologies in the project form. Validate the project object if you want it to have at least one technology or similar constraint. Use a select on the whole "Technology" table to do the search box. And use

```
if search_tech_id.present?
  _projects = _projects.joins(:technologies).where("technologies.id" => search_tech_id)
end
```

instead of all that stuff concatenating LIKEs

EDIT: a way to search for projects related to many techs.

To allow searching for "many techs" you can use a multiselect field. You can also add an option for "AND"-ing or "OR"-ing the conditions (that is, search for porjocets related to all the selected techs or any of the selected techs.

In the controller, when you get the list of tech IDs, to search for projects with ALL the selected techs you have to use some SQL magic:

```
n_techs = search_techs_ids.size
_projects = _projects.joins(:technologies).
              select("projects.*").
              where("technologies.id" => search_tech_ids).
              group("projects.*").
              having("count(technologies.id) = #{n_techs}")
```

On the other side, to search for ANY tech among the selected ones, you can do

```
_projects = _projects.joins(:technologies).
              where("technologies.id" => search_tech_ids)
```

Comment: I attempted to use a joined table to hold the many technologies for each project. I then had trouble searching for a project, with many technologies.

Comment: I have updated my question with all my code that relates to my problem. @saverio

Comment: Thanks for helping again. I am so confused now. Are both of your code suggestions to go in my project model? See my code in the updated version

Comment: The former is to be applied if you want to select project for *all* of the selected techs, the latter is for *any* of them. Put a radio button or checkbox if you want to use both, and execute one or the other depending on the user's selection

Comment: But you can't use this with your current models, you have to create a Technology model and a has_and_belongs_to_many relation with Project.

Comment: I have opened a new question, as I have changed a lot of my app thanks to your help. I am still having problems though. Could you take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693229/ruby-on-rails-table-relationship-search